# Android DatePickerWithNowButton adds extra date header

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepickerdialog

I have a `DatePickerWithNowButton` that is displayed when the user clicks on a `TextView`. Sometimes however when the `DatePickerWithNowButton` is displayed it adds a gray "extra" header on top of the `DatePickerWithNowButton` as can bee seen in this image:

[image]

Here the code I'm using:

```
@Override
    public void onChooseDateClicked() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date(chosenDepartDate));
        final DatePickerWithNowButton dpd = new DatePickerWithNowButton(getActivity(), EditSearchFragment.this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(DateTimeManager.getInstance().getBestUTCTimeAtTheMoment());

        Calendar maxCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        maxCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 86);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxCal.getTimeInMillis());

        dpd.show();

        dpd.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        onDateSet(null, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                        dpd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        dpd.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dpd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    }
```

I haven't encountered this before. Anyone have any idea what's going on. As I said it happens sometimes and sometimes it looks as it should without the gray extra header. And it also changes the dates to the date I select in the calendar.

Comment: Have you got any solution? I know this issue comes after adding setMaxDate, but I am searching for the solution to remove extra header.

Comment: Nope no solution unfortunately